# How to get the WTSClientAddress from the java.lang.Object getClientInfo()

Tags: java, windows, terminal-services, oracleforms

In one of our current web application we are using the [getClientInfo](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/products/forms/extracted/getclientinfo/src/oracle/forms/demos/GetClientInfo.java)() from a [java.lang.Object](http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/products/forms/extracted/getclientinfo/doc/oracle.forms.demos.GetClientInfo.html) reference in our Oracle Forms application which works great for egtting the client IP address of a system.

However we recently started to use Windows Terminal Servers in our organization, and we are now having the problem with this code returning back the IP address of the terminal server and not the IP address of the of the system which is running the TS session.

I know there is native windows function that can return the session IP using the [`WTSQuerySessionInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383838(VS.85).aspx) function of `user32.dll`, and then access the pointer to [`WTSClientAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383857(VS.85).aspx) to get the session IP.

However, I don't know how to access this type of information within the Oracle Forms Java development environment.

Does anyone know how I might got about doing this using the `WTSClientAddress` parameter from the `WTSQuerySessionInformation API` ?

Comment: This question doesn't make much sense - as java.lang.Object doesn't have a method named getClientInfo() ...

Comment: From what I understand its a bean which is available in Oracle Forms:
http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/products/forms/extracted/getclientinfo/src/oracle/forms/demos/GetClientInfo.java

http://www.oracle.com/technology/sample_code/products/forms/extracted/getclientinfo/doc/oracle.forms.demos.GetClientInfo.html